# Jquery Exact Count of a li elemnt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an element(ul) that the width can be changed depending on the number of element(li) contained in this (ul).
I used jquery to get this done but i don't get the right result as i'm making an error and i don't how to fix it. 
here is my jquery code:

```
jQuery('ul.class').each(function(){
    var n = jQuery('ul.class li').length;
    console.log(n);
    jQuery(this).css('width',n*(jQuery('ul.class li').width() + 10));
    console.log(n*jQuery('ul.class li').width());
});
```

10 in this code is the border or each element.

The issue is in this part `var n = jQuery('ul.class li').length` and i don't know of to get the exact count of each li contained in a ul.

li has a width 150px

Comment: Use `jQuery("li", this).length`. [The second parameter of `jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) let's you define the element to be searched in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery('ul.class').each(function(){
   var n = jQuery(this).find('li').length;
   alert(n);
   jQuery(this).css('width',n*(jQuery(this).find('li').width() + 10));
   alert(n*jQuery(this).find('li').width());
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/84Bv6/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working. so the error was that i count the global number of li element contained in this class?

Comment: @Yazid, Can you please create fiddle for your issue?